# Vanilla snippets for Sublime Text 2?

Tags: code-snippets, sublimetext, sublimetext2

I'm looking for simple snippets for JavaScript and CSS. Just things like `function`, so I can hit autocomplete and tab through the function name, arguments and contents. I can't seem to find anything like this? It would also be nice to have this for jQuery. I've seen some IDEs where suggestions will appear as you type, along with documentation about the method you are using, such as the arguments it takes. Is there anything like this out there for jQuery or JavaScript? Finally, is there anything decent for CSS? All of the things I seem to find just provide shortcuts like `vh` for `visibility: hidden;`. This is not what I want! I just want Sublime to **know** the language I am writing.

Looking inside the default packages for things like CSS, there **are** snippets defined. For example, snippets for `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`. But they each the tab trigger of `margin`. I just want to be able to write `margin-top` or `margin-bottom` and somewhere along the line, press tab and be taken to the value (with a semicolon afterwards). I don't want "shortcuts".

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Sublime Snippets, which are stored in the 'Packages\User' directory.

For example;

Filename

```
function.sublime-snippet
```

Contents

```
<snippet>
    <content>
    <![CDATA[

    ${1:private} function ${2:name}(${3:argument}) {
        ${4:content}
    }

    ]]>
    </content>
    <tabTrigger>function</tabTrigger>
    <description>Function</description>
    <scope>source.php</scope>
</snippet>
```

I've added this to my GitHub project, which includes a number of useful snippets you can use - simply check the GitHub project out to the 'Packages\User' directory.

For your margin-top example, you'd setup a snippet like this;

```
<snippet>
    <content>
    <![CDATA[margin-top: $1;]]>
    </content>
    <tabTrigger>margin-top</tabTrigger>
    <description>Margin Top</description>
    <scope>source.css</scope>
</snippet>
```

One I find very useful, is the jQuery CDN snippet, which gives you a very quick jQuery, jQuery UI and jQuery UI CSS setup, with full fallback.

Feel free to contribute to my snippets:
https://github.com/olimortimer/sublime-snippets

Answer (score 0):

Try the SublimeCodeIntel package:

https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel

Both JavaScript and CSS are included, among others.

Answer (score 0):

I have completions for CSS, JavaScript and jQuery available on [GitHub](https://github.com/agibsonsw/AndySublime).

I remove all the existing CSS snippets out of the Packages/CSS folder as I find they get in the way.

Mine contain a number of features. For example, typing 'b' for a colour (in CSS) yields 'blue', but 'bl' yields 'black'. And triggering 'aler' for 'alert()' in HTML will prepend 'window.' (if there isn't already a variable attached).

I also adjust the auto-complete delay so the completions don't appear too quickly.

For the jQuery completions you will need a jQuery syntax (tmLanguage) file. Alternatively, modify my file to use scope 'source.js' so that they appear for any '.js' file.

(The CodeIntel Package is out of date and not maintained.)